Can anyone help me identify this piece?

Found this in a second hand game i bought, anyone know what it is from? Already tried google image searching it and nothing came up!

This is Terra Mystica - see http://gamesoncloud.blogspot.com/2014/01/terra-mystica.html, search on "◎配件很多，克勞德用天鵝堡買的大收納盒將所有公用配件都放在裡面" - I'm just trying to find a more authoritative (and English) source.

It's a score-in-excess-of-100 token from Terra Mystica.
See upper left token on this unpunched sheet:

Or as stored on the right in this custom storage solution:


There's another example at https://thedicetroyers.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/TheDicetroyers_TerraMysticaAllIn-07-1024x683.jpg which is perhaps clearer to make out.
